# How to prompt user to login into his OneDrive and not use the connected account?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I was building a Windows 8.1 universal phone App by using the LiveAuthClient . I'm able to login and upload/download data from OneDrive with the connected account. But **I wanted to provide a username-password prompt so he can use a different OneDrive account and not just his connected account**. And I could not find a proper documentation regarding this. I'm using a LiveSDK 5.6.

Currently the code:

```
    LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
    LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<String>() { "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.skydrive" });
    if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {                

           LiveConnectClient meClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);
           string sCurrentRootID = "me/skydrive";
           LiveOperationResult result = await meClient.GetAsync(sCurrentRootID + "/files");
           //process the result here
    }
```